# Show $X \setminus ( X\setminus A) =A$ using element argument

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show

$$X \setminus ( X\setminus A) =A$$

---

doing some self studying on Croom's book on principles of topology. I am able to prove it using sets but not element argument on left way

**Easy prove** using sets and thm 1.2 if $A \subset B $ it is equivalient to $A 
\cap B =A$

$$\begin{aligned}
X \setminus (X \setminus A) &=X \cap (X \setminus A)^c
                           \\ &= X \cap( X^c \cup A) 
                             \\ &= (X \cap X^c) \cup (X \cap A)
                          \\ & = \emptyset \cup  (X \cap A)
             \\ & =   (X \cap A)
                 \\ &=A &&\text{since } A \subset X \Leftrightarrow  A \cap X = A
\end{aligned} $$

proving using set element notation

$\Rightarrow$] *($X \setminus (X \setminus A) \subset A$)*

assume that $x \in X \setminus (X \setminus A)$ so $x\in X \wedge x\not \in X \setminus A \Leftrightarrow  x\in X \wedge (x\not \in X \vee x\in A)$ 
by disjoing syllogims $x\in A$

$\Leftarrow ]$  *could use help here thanks! Using element argument ofcourse*

Comment: Suppose $x\in A$.  Then $x\notin X\setminus A$.  Since $x\in A$ it follows that $x\in X$ as well.  Therefore since $x\in X$ and $x\notin X\setminus A$...

Comment: Nitpick.  You never stated that X was the universal set or that A was a subset of X.  This isn't true if A is not a subset of X.

Comment: @fleablood. Very good nitpick. Hidden assumptions, no matter how small, are the bane of all attempts at reasoning.

Comment: @fleablood Unwilling to upvote your comment because you say it is a nitpick. It is not.

Comment: It's a nitpick about the post.  Not about the math.  It is *essential* that *someone* indicated that $X$ is a universal or at least a superset.  And I assume someone did.  This is a nitpick for the *poster* for (probably-- I'm giving the benefit of the doubt) assuming it was self-evident and not bothering to point it out.  But you are right.  The necessity is *not* a nitpick.