# Show $ A \subset X \implies X \setminus ( X\setminus A) =A $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

There is also a similar question on this topic here : [Show $X \setminus ( X\setminus A) =A$ using element argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2282882/show-x-setminus-x-setminus-a-a-using-element-argument?rq=1)

What I want to show is that :

$$ A \subset X \implies X \setminus ( X\setminus A) =A $$

I merely understoodd what the author of the question I mentionned above had done. Could you please give me some advices in order to prove the statement? Multiple ways to do it is accepted. In fact, the statement seems totally true but I have no clue how to do it.

Comment: Let $P(x)$ be some property for the variable $x$. Let $\neg$ denote the negation operator. For example, $\neg(x=y)\iff x\ne y$. The biggest hint I can give you is $\neg\neg P(x)\iff P(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can treat $X$ as the universal set so that *by definition* $x \in X \setminus Y \iff x \notin Y.$ Thus

$$a \in X \setminus (X \setminus A) \iff a \notin X \setminus A \iff a \in A$$
meaning $X \setminus (X \setminus A) = A$.

Comment: "the universal set" is a problematic notion for several reasons.

Comment: I think Arthur is suggesting that you start your sentence with "by definition $x\in X\setminus Y\iff x\in X\text{ and }x\notin Y$"